Metric for Measuring Similarity of Z2-Symmetric binary Vectors
Apologies if this question is somewhat physics-related, but I believe it has a strong statistical component that fits within the scope of Cross Validated SE.
I have two vectors $S$ and $S_{\text{noise}}$, each consisting of elements that can either be $1$ or $-1$. These vectors represent the ground state and a noise-affected state of a Hamiltonian system, respectively. An important characteristic of these vectors is that they exhibit Z2 symmetry, meaning $S$ and $-S$ are considered equivalent.
I want to find a metric that measures the similarity or difference between these two vectors, taking into account the Z2 symmetry. Ideally, the metric should:

Be monotonic and normalized between 0 and 1, where 0 indicates identical vectors (including $S = -S_{\text{noise}}$) and 1 indicates completely dissimilar vectors.
Be invariant under the Z2 symmetry transformation, i.e., the similarity measure should be the same for $(S, S_{\text{noise}})$ and $(S, -S_{\text{noise}})$.

What would be a suitable metric for this purpose?

Assume your vectors are all of length $n$.
Count the number of entries where $S$ and $S_\text{noise}$ differ. Call this number $r$.
Count the number of entries where $S$ and $-S_\text{noise}$ differ. Call this number $s$.
Then $r+s=n$, because $S$ and $S_\text{noise}$ differ exactly in those entries where $S$ and $-S_\text{noise}$ do not differ. And of course these two numbers are also the numbers of entries where $-S$ and $-S_\text{noise}$ differ, and where $-S$ and $S_\text{noise}$ differ, so we are accounting for the symmetry in both vectors.
We will use $\min\{r,s\}$ as your metric. This is a number between $0$ and $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. So we normalize it and use:
$$ d(S,S_\text{noise}) = d(S,-S_\text{noise}) = 
d(-S,S_\text{noise}) = d(-S,-S_\text{noise}) := 
\frac{\min\{r,s\}}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}. $$
